# how to replace string with '$' in unix using sed

Tags: unix, search, sed, replace

I'm trying to replace string `#########` to `$` in all files in `$HOME/findreplace/` directory with below statements but I'm getting `sed: Function s_#########_ cannot be parsed.` error.

Thanks in advance for you help.

```
for file in $HOME/findreplace/*.*
do
    sed -e "s_#########_$_g" $file> /tmp/tempfile.tmp
    mv /tmp/tempfile.tmp $file
    echo "Modified: " $file
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
for file in $HOME/findreplace/*.*
do
    sed -i 's/#########/\$/g' "$file"
    echo "Modified:  $file"
done
```

**Explanation:**

- Use `/` instead where you had `_` before to separate the pattern to match and pattern to replace.
- Use `\` to escape the `$` char
- Use single quotes instead of double quotes to avoid having bash auto-expand something (string enclosed by single quotes will be interpreted literally)
- Use the `-i` option to `sed` to do in-place editing, so you can avoid having to use a temp file.
- You almost always want to enclose your variables (such as `$file`) in double-quotes.